# SFDX Pull not grabbing reports

Tags: reporting, salesforcedx

I'm trying to pull reports that I am creating in my Scratch Org, however sfdx force:source:pull doesn't seem to be grabbing the reports.

I have them in the Unfiled Public folder. I even created a meta.xml file for it in my project and it pushed correctly but when I updated via my scratch org it doesn't show any changes.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue, have a look [here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1&fId=0D53A00003YDLOt&s1oid=00D300000000iTz&OpenCommentForEdit=1&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1nid=0DB30000000072L&emtm=1530827018140&s1uid=00530000003Jora&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0).

Comment: Well that is unfortunate, thank you for this find Fabien!